# the unfamiliar usage of 'reward'

Tags: word-usage

The passage below comes from the webpage, reddit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/comments/6cvlnv/korean_politician_swag/?sort=old

> This is actually sad and not "swag". Humanity should not ***reward*** such a
>   self centered and scummy character.

I am not familiar with the usage of the verb, REWARD in this context and however hard I check on Google, I couldn't find any similar usage of 'reward' to this one.

If I wrote the same sentence myself, I would do it as follows:

> We should not ***reward*** humanity to such a self centered and scummy character.

Or,

> Such a self centered and scummy character should not ***be rewarded*** with humanity.

Do you agree with me?

Comment: Humanity is the subject here, not the object.  Humanity is doing the rewarding.

Comment: You just need to look a little deeper into online dictionaries. Definition 1.1 of the verb in Oxford Dictionaries is what you're looking for: ["*Show one's appreciation of (an action or quality)*"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reward). Check out the examples there, too.

Comment: A misconception here, I think. 'Humanity' in this context means 'people in general', not 'treating someone humanely'.

Comment: The sentence is saying *no one should be offering rewards* for bad behavior.